# Is there a way to show only the top 2/nth of a query after "group by" country? - bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, filter, google-bigquery, ranking

I am doing a query on Google Big query, I have joined the 2 tables and created a new column "total gmv" using "SUM" to represent the total revenue, now I wanted to show only the top 2 vendors , GROUP BY country in my query.

I manage to show total_gmv group by COUNTRY and vendor_name, but I would like to filter to show top 2 vendors for each country only.

Code I used

```
SELECT Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name, round(sum(Ord.gmv_local),2) as total_gmv FROM ORDERS as Ord
left join `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Vendors` as vn
ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
GROUP BY Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name
ORDER BY Ord.country_name, total_gmv desc
```

| country_name | vendor_name | total_gmv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Singapore | A House | 1583.25 |
| Singapore | B House | 1236.35 |
| Singapore | C House | 1153.27 |
| Singapore | D House | 596.21 |
| Hong Kong | H House | 1888.75 |
| Hong Kong | K House | 755.78 |
| Bangkok | BB House | 936.12 |

**Is there a way to show only the top 2 vendors per country?**

**My target table should look like this, showing top 2 only**

I am using Google bigquery and it seems the "TOP 2" function doesn't work?

| country_name | vendor_name | total_gmv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Singapore | A House | 1583.25 |
| Singapore | B House | 1236.35 |
| Hong Kong | H House | 1888.75 |
| Hong Kong | K House | 755.78 |
| Bangkok | BB House | 936.12 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name, ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ord.country_name
                              ORDER BY SUM(Ord.gmv_local) DESC) rn
    FROM ORDERS AS Ord
    LEFT JOIN `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Vendors` AS vn
        ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
    GROUP BY Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name
)

SELECT country_name, vendor_name, total_gmv
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY country_name, total_gmv DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a lifesaver Tim :)

Comment: @HKChan I have given you an answer to follow-up question.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to go - just one extra line in your code
`QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY total_gmv DESC) <= 2`

So, the whole quesry now will be

```
SELECT 
  Ord.country_name, 
  vn.vendor_name, 
  round(sum(Ord.gmv_local),2) as total_gmv 
FROM ORDERS as Ord
LEFT JOIN `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Vendors` as vn
ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
GROUP BY Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY country_name ORDER BY total_gmv DESC) <= 2
ORDER BY Ord.country_name desc, total_gmv desc
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]