# Find the top 2 vendors per country, in each year available in the dataset? - bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, filter, google-bigquery, datetime-format, partitioning

I've joined 2 tables and extract the top 2 vendors by country (code at the bottom of this post and link) with the help of Tim Biegeleisen on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67913960/is-there-a-way-to-show-only-the-top-2-nth-of-a-query-after-group-by-country) , now I would like to go 1 step further and group the top 2 vendors by year by country.

The original ORDERS table looks like this :

| country_name | date_local | vendor_id | gmv_local | is_successful_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | 2870 | 559.6 | true |
| Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | 3812 | 573.5 | true |
| Singapore | 2012-10-02 | 941 | 778.6 | true |
| Singapore | 2014-10-02 | 13 | 120.6 | true |
| Bangkok | 2014-10-02 | 227 | 563.6 | true |

This table is merged with the vendor table

| id | vendor_name | country_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2870 | C House | Taiwan |
| 941 | A House | Singapore |
| 227 | 9 House | Bangkok |

I would like to extract the year from the "date_local" column into timestamp format, where the items in the Year column will look like "2012-01-01T00:00:00" from the original date format of "2012-10-02"

Then I would like to list out the top 2 vendors of by year of each country in total revenue

The resulting table should look like this:

| year | country_name | vendor_name | total_gmv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01T00:00:00 | Singapore | A House | 1119.76 |
| 2012-01-01T00:00:00 | Singapore | B House | 819.63 |
| 2012-01-01T00:00:00 | Taiwan | C House | 119.6 |
| 2012-01-01T00:00:00 | Taiwan | D House | 119.6 |
| 2012-01-01T00:00:00 | Bangkok | 9 House | 119.6 |
| 2014-01-01T00:00:00 | Singapore | A House | 2119.76 |
| 2014-01-01T00:00:00 | Singapore | B House | 1819.63 |
| 2014-01-01T00:00:00 | Taiwan | C House | 1019.6 |
| 2014-01-01T00:00:00 | Taiwan | D House | 919.6 |
| 2014-01-01T00:00:00 | Bangkok | 9 House | 189.6 |

[printscreen of target results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1SSm.png)

I know I need to add one more partition of the `Extract( year FROM date_local) as year` and set it to the correct `GETDATE()` timestamp format to add the extra layer needed, but I don't know how to add it to the code

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name, ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ord.country_name
                              ORDER BY SUM(Ord.gmv_local) DESC) rn
    FROM `Orders` AS Ord
    LEFT JOIN `Vendors` AS vn
        ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
    GROUP BY Ord.country_name, vn.vendor_name
)

SELECT country_name, vendor_name, total_gmv
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 1
ORDER BY country_name, total_gmv DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only need to also aggregate by year, and then add year to the partition of the call to `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) AS year,
    ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv
FROM ORDERS AS Ord
LEFT JOIN `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Vendors` AS vn
    ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
GROUP BY
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_name, EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)
                           ORDER BY total_gmv DESC) <= 2
ORDER BY
    Ord.country_name DESC,
    total_gmv DESC;
```

Comment: I am hitting an error message below, not sure what it means :

SELECT list expression references column date_local which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:23]

Comment: Are you certain that you ran the _exact_ answer you see above?  I don't think my query should be generating this error message.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have a further question on this question, I would like to show the best 2 vendors of each country with the highest improvement in total GMV between 2012 and 2014, link below for the question, could you help me with the further deepdive?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68082180/find-the-top-2-vendors-per-country-with-the-most-total-revenue-increase-in-each

Answer (score 0):

I am also hitting an error message like this: SELECT list expression references column date_local which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:23]. How will I make it right?

It is my first time here at StackOverflow that is why I cannot comment. Thank you!