# Find the top 2 vendors per country with the most total revenue increase, in each year available in the dataset? - bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, row, ranking

I've joined 2 tables and extract the top 2 vendors by country (code at the bottom of this post and link) with the help of Tim Biegeleisen on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914891/find-the-top-2-vendors-per-country-in-each-year-available-in-the-dataset-big), now I would like to go 1 step further and show the best 2 vendors of each country with the highest improvement in total GMV between 2012 and 2014.

The original ORDERS table looks like this :

| country_name | date_local | vendor_id | gmv_local | is_successful_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | 2870 | 559.6 | true |
| Taiwan | 2012-10-02 | 3812 | 573.5 | true |
| Singapore | 2012-10-02 | 941 | 778.6 | true |
| Singapore | 2014-10-02 | 13 | 120.6 | true |
| Bangkok | 2014-10-02 | 227 | 563.6 | true |

This table is merged with the vendor table

| id | vendor_name | country_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2870 | C House | Taiwan |
| 941 | A House | Singapore |
| 227 | 9 House | Bangkok |

I would like to show only the top 2 vendors by country for highest improvement in total GMV between 2012 and 2014

2 new columns should be added "2012_total_gmv"- show 2012 total_gmv for this vendor_name and "diff_gmv" - calculate the difference of total_gmv

Then I would like to list out the top 2 vendors of by year of each country in total revenue

The resulting table should look like this:

| Year | country_name | vendor_name | total_gmv | 2012_total_gmv | diff_gmv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | Singapore | A House | 2119.76 | 1119.76 | 1000 |
| 2014 | Singapore | B House | 1819.63 | 819.63 | 1000 |
| 2014 | Taiwan | C House | 1019.6 | 119.6 | 1000 |
| 2014 | Taiwan | F House | 819.6 | 119.6 | 700 |
| 2014 | Bangkok | XXX House | 1289.6 | 189.6 | 1100 |

I am trying the LAG() function I found on another website to approach this and would like help on the work is open if there better ways to get the results

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) AS year,
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) AS total_gmv,
    LAG(ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2)) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) ) AS previous_year,
    ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2) - LAG(ROUND(SUM(Ord.gmv_local), 2))
    OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) ) AS difference_previous_year
FROM `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Orders` AS Ord
LEFT JOIN `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Vendors` AS vn
    ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
GROUP BY
    Ord.country_name,
    vn.vendor_name,
    date_local
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_name, EXTRACT(year FROM date_local)
    ORDER BY total_gmv DESC) <= 2
ORDER BY
    year, Ord.country_name,
    total_gmv DESC;
```

Comment: I'm lost.  How is total GMV calculated?  What does the query have to do with the question?  What is, in fact, the source data and what are the results you want?

Comment: Hi Gordon, the total_gmv is calculated by Summing the individual vendor_name's gmv_local together

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT Ord.country_name,
       vn.vendor_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2012 THEN dOrd.gmv_local END) AS total_gmv_2012,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2014 THEN dOrd.gmv_local END) AS total_gmv_2014
FROM `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Orders` Ord LEFT JOIN
     `primeval-falcon-306603.foodpanda_BI_Exercise.Vendors` AS vn
     ON Ord.vendor_id = vn.id
GROUP BY Ord.country_name,
        vn.vendor_name
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ord.country_name ORDER BY total_gmv_2014 - total_gmv_2012 DESC) <= 2;
```

Note:  This assumes that "improvement" is the difference rather than a ratio.

Comment: Thanks you for the help Gordon, I am also trying to show the difference of 2012 vs 2014 as a new column "diff_gmv"

```SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2014 THEN Ord.gmv_local END) - SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2012 THEN Ord.gmv_local END) AS diff_gmv
```

But I am not getting the results, could you help me with this? Thanks in advance again

Comment: @HKChan . . . Your expression looks correct.  Perhaps you just need `else 0` for vendors that don't have data in both years.

Comment: Thanks Gordon , however It's still not showing the correct value in the column, ```(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2014 THEN Ord.gmv_local ELSE 0 END)) - (SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM date_local) = 2012 THEN Ord.gmv_local ELSE 0 END)) AS diff_gmv```